# CakeTime 31/12/2012 to 2012-12-31?

Tags: cakephp, date, format

I am trying to format an date received as 31/12/2012 to 2012-12-31.

I have used ::format and ::toServer, but I get 2012-31-12 instead of 2012-12-31.

How can I do it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//via Time helper
echo $this->Time->format('Y-m-d', "31/12/2012");

//via CakeTime utility
echo CakeTime::format('Y-m-d', "31/12/2012");
```

From CakePHP 1.3 manual:

> (...) format is a wrapper for the PHP date function.